# How do i secure[hardening] existing Ubuntu productions servers?

Tags: server, security

I would like to apply server hardening policy[securing] on existing Ubuntu production servers. Will lead any issues after applying? What is the best practices to apply hardening on existing production environments.

Comment: Tips&tricks: http://blog.mattbrock.co.uk/hardening-the-security-on-ubuntu-server-14-04/ and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1002167 and our own help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind! Gone through shared URLs..However, my question is, i want to secure the servers on existing production environments[Applications/Databases]. Will lead any issue if i apply those recommended steps?

Answer (score 3):

Best practices: Understand what the production servers do (deep internals), and consider whether or not your "hardening" will interfere with what they do.

"Harden" your test servers first.

A tool that I like is `lynis` from [cisofy.com](https://cisofy.com/). It is free, and makes no changes, just points to vulnerabilities.

Realize that security/hardening is a process, not a paint. You cannot just spay it on once (and succeed).

Comment: Thanks Waltinator for ur valuable information! Will look on it and will update feedback after tested...